# get select values inside div ,then show children div of main div

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="question>
   <select name="status">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
   </select>
   <div class="subquestion">
    <input type="file name="file>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".question").each(function () {
        $(".subquestion").hide();
        $('select[name=status]').click(function () {
            if (this.value == "1" || this.value == "2" || this.value == "3") {
                // show $(this) div 'subquestion'
            }
            else {
               $(".subquestion").hide();
            }
        })
    })
});
```

I want to get select values with this select values and then if values are 1 || 2 || 3 then use this div subquestion show();
but it must be outside of if statement beacause there is selected ('select') tag and div subquestion is outside that tag.

Comment: How can the value be anything else, you've included all of them?

Comment: FYI, you wrote `<input type="file name="file>`, it should have been `<input type="file" name="file">`, you missed some quotes :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to show the `subquestion` related to that question use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".question").each(function () {
        $(".subquestion").hide();
        $('select[name=status]').change(function () {
            if (this.value == "1" || this.value == "2" || this.value == "3") {
                $(this).next('.subquestion').show();
            }
            else {
               $(this).next('.subquestion').hide();
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/6ZxDJ/

Comment: Np mate glad to help you @HadesNebula

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
           $('select[name=status]').click(function () {
                if (this.value == "1" || this.value == "2" || this.value == "3") {
                    // show $(this) div 'subquestion'
                }
                else {
                   $(".subquestion").hide();
                }
            })
```

to this

```
           $('select[name="status"]').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "1" || $(this).val() == "2" || $(this).val() == "3") {
                    $(this).closest('.question').find(".subquestion").show();
                }
                else {
                   $(this).closest('.question').find(".subquestion").hide();
                }
            })
```

Comment: this code will display all divs with class  subquestion... i want exactly that div inside... (this form is in cycle)

Comment: You are still hidding all `subquestion` elements